# Wrap text around image using css3

Tags: html, css

Surprisingly, I cannot find an answer to the simple question - how to wrap text around image?
I have dynamically generated (user-entered) text and image, and I need to fit it in the div, like that:
[image: Div with text and image]
Or, in case there's not enough text, it shall be like that:
[image]
In other words, image shall be displayed in place it is set to and shall be wrapped by text. I thought it would be easy but suddenly cannot find how to do that, please help, I suppose there's a simple way to achieve that.

Comment: it's not possible, simply imagine how the browser can handle this ... it's intuitive for you but not as a simple as you think. You need JS and a lot of hacks

Comment: Sure! It's hard to imagine even how browser handles "float" or even "grid" - it's a kinda miracle! Although, w3.org could buy a technology from m$ or openoffice - they implemented this somehow lol. It could be something like "float: here" if you understand what am I talking about )))

Comment: there is something close called `shape-outside` but still far from this ... and the purpose of w3 is to provide specification not implementation ;) it's up to browser to implement and to developer ... so you can probably think about this and implement it as JS plugin where you create your `float;here` ;)

Comment: I'm just kidding, don't be offended )) Nothing difficult to implement this, for sure. And if there will be spec, there would be an implementation as well. But I suppose it is possible somehow - it's so trivial, it cannot be that there's no way to make that. Let's wait for others answers. I know about shapes, so, you see, it could be implemented lol
I need the same but for img.

Comment: if you will get an answer you will simply get a hacky JS answer ;) there is no way to do this with CSS, believe me :) ... only a complex hacky code can approximate this and it won't be generic.

Comment: Why, if you and me don't know the answer, it does not mean there's none ) let's wait and check ))

Comment: because I know what CSS can do, and it's not that I don't know the answer but I know that there is no CSS property for this. I simply said that something like this need to be achieved with some JS, CSS is limited .. so if you really want an answer I advice you to add the JS tag, also add the CSS tag to target more people

Comment: It's nice you believe you know everything, but let me check that with others answers ))) Sure, I can do some ecmascript workaround, it's simple and easy, but I need a css/html solution.

Comment: ok keep waiting then :) but better add more tags to attract more people, you can still add 3.

Comment: I don't need to lol. You could create your own question and I'd answer you how to do that with js )))

Comment: @falconimogollon before editing you may check the comments, the OP doesn't want JS even if he's not convinced that there is no way with pure CSS

Comment: In theory, this is possible with CSS Exclusions (https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/03/16/css-exclusions-and-grid-layout/), but in practice, they are supported only in MS Edge yet.

Comment: Well, so, not possible really. Unbelievable.

Comment: Please add this as an answer, so I could accept it. 10x.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible but it's so advance that you need a lot of js and css to manipulate the flow. Assuming the blue rectangles are html tag where you can put your text, let's say a `div`. For example the text  from **rA** will continue to **rB** then to **rC**. This one will continue downwards until its total height is equal to the height of the element in the middle, let's say an image. Basically the thought is making the texts jump from one div to the other when it overflows. Found this one on this [website](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-regions-1/) [image].

Comment: so it short: it's not possible with *only* CSS ;)